# pkg-config: print Requires.private without being recursive

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries, libraries, pkg-config

I have a problem which I think I can solve if I manage to get from `pkg-config` the list in Requires.private without being recursive.  First I'll post the problem, and then my try to workaround it.

---

Problem:

I had a static-only library (let's call it `libfoo.a`) with no `pkg-config` files, which I just included as a submodule of my programs.  I had to take into account in the program makefile all the dependencies that my library might have, because as a static library, it didn't carry the information of which shared library it depended on.  That meant that I had to dinamically link with a lot of libraries in my programs' makefiles, but that worked.

Example:

```
$(CC) $(OBJS) -o $@ -L path/foo/ -l foo `pkg-config --libs opencv gsl ncurses`
```

It worked, because it could only find a static version of libfoo, and after that it had a list of what libfoo needed (instead of what the program actually needed dinamically).

Now I have improved that library so that it is installed in `/usr/local/`, provide `pkg-config` files, and both `.a` and `.so` files.

When I link dinamically to my library, everything is fine.

When I try to link statically, if the program doesn't use `opencv` at all, it is fine (I don't know if it's opencv that is broken when trying to link statically, or that I broke it installing some updates from the testing repo;  if I had a clean installation I would know, but I don't).  The problem comes when I try to link statically, and some opencv is used.  There are some libraries not found, so what I thought as a solution is to replicate what happened before I installed my library.

But now I don't want to hardcode my library's dependencies in my program's makefile, so I use pkg-config.

---

My try:

Assuming that my program only depends directly on libfoo, and libfoo depends on opencv, gsl and ncurses directly (which my program ignores), this is what I would do:

```
$(CC) $(OBJS) -o $@ -Wl,-Bstatic `pkg-config --libs foo` -Wl,-Bdynamic `pkg-config --static --libs foo`
```

the first pkg-config is to expose only libfoo to be linked statically, and the second one is to expose libfoo's dependencies to be linked dinamically.  But the problem is that I'm exposing, not only libfoo's direct dependencies, but also all the recursive dependencies, which I don't want to.

Is there any way to expose only the direct dependencies?  Or is there any other workaround to this situation?

---

In this case, it is needed to the problem with a broken openCV, and someone could say: hey, just solve that problem with openCV, and forget about that.

But this is also useful for someone who wants to link statically to a library which performance is critical, but still link dinamically to other heavier libraries which aren't as critical.

---

System:

Debian 10

GCC 8

OpenCV might have some packages or dependencies installed from testing.

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into this, and I think I'm going to have to write a bit of Python to just repeatedly call `pkg-config`.